# Adding delay to render page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, delay

So my problem is that I'm trying to render a page but I also want to return a 404 error when an Id is not found. But when accessing an existing id it faster returns a 404 error because of the time to retrieve the data from the database, so for the first second or so it returns a 404 page and then it renders the page. So I want to add a delay before it renders the page or if someone else has a better solution for this is also good. This is my itempage component.

```
const ItemPage: React.FC = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState<Item>();
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState<number>(1);
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
    const id = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState<number>(0);
    const [size, setSize] = useState<string>("Small");
    const [authenticationMessage, setAuthenticationMessage] = useState<string>("");
    const [popupMessage, setPopupMessage] = useState<string>("");
    const nav = useNavigate();
    const imageMap: { [key: number]: string[] } = {
        1: nascarImages,
        2: heartlessImages,
        3: anotherImages
    }
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const jwt = cookies.get("jwttoken");

    useEffect(() => {
        getItem();
        setImages(imageMap[parseInt(id)]);
        setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
        getUserFromStorage();
        wait(500);
      }, [images]);

    const wait = (ms: number) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        });
    }
    const getItem = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await itemService.getItemById(parseInt(id));
            setItem(res.data.product);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    const getUserFromStorage = async () => {
        const id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
        if (id !== null) {
            const res = await userService.getUserById(parseInt(id), jwt);
            setUser(res.data.user);
        }
    }

    const nextImage = () => {
        if (imageIndex === images.length - 1) {
            setImageIndex(0);
        } else {
            setImageIndex(imageIndex + 1);
        }
        console.log(imageIndex);
    };

    const previousImage = () => {
        if (imageIndex === 0) {
            setImageIndex(images.length - 1);
        } else {
            setImageIndex(imageIndex - 1);
        }
        console.log(imageIndex);
    };

    const addToCart = async () => {
        if (user === undefined) {
            setAuthenticationMessage("You need to be logged in to add items to cart");
        }
        if (user !== undefined && item !== undefined) {
            console.log("in the if statement");
            try {
                const res = await cartService.addToCart(user.id, item.id, quantity, size, jwt);
                if (res && res.status == "success") {
                    setPopupMessage("Item succesfully added to cart");
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setPopupMessage("");
                    }
                    , 3000);
                }
                if (res && res.status == "unauthorized") {
                    setPopupMessage("It seems that you are not authenticated anymore, please login again");
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setPopupMessage("");
                    }
                    , 3000);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    };
    if (item === undefined) {
        return <NotFound />;
      }
    return (
        <div className="itemContainer">
          <div className="itemImages">
            <button className="leftArrow" onClick={previousImage}></button>
            <img className="itemPicture" src={images[imageIndex]} alt="logo" />
            <button className="rightArrow" onClick={nextImage}></button>
          </div>
          <div className="itemInfo">
            <div className="itemTitle">
              <h1 className="itemHeader">{item.name}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className={`popupMessage ${popupMessage.length === 0 ? '' : 'show'}`}>
                <p className="popupText">{popupMessage}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p className="itemDescription">{item.description}</p>
            </div>
            <button className="toCartButton" onClick={addToCart}>
              Add to cart
            </button>
            {authenticationMessage !== "" ? (
                <p className="authenticationMessage">{authenticationMessage}</p>
            ) : (
                <></>
            )}
            <div className="sizeContainer">
                <button className="sizeButton" onClick={()=>setSize("Small")}>S</button>
                <button className="sizeButton" onClick={()=>setSize("Medium")}>M</button>
                <button className="sizeButton" onClick={()=>setSize("Large")}>L</button>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}
export default ItemPage;
```

As you can see I've tried adding a delay but it still returns the 404 and then the right data. All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: just add a loader when you are fetching the data

Comment: What do you mean with loader?